# Javascript/JQuery Math.random to onclick fade to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a simple game for my school project and the basic Idea is when you press a button to start the game random images will fade in and you have to click as many of them as you can in 30 seconds. I am using Math.random and Javascript for if statements and JQuery for its built in onclick and fadeTo. The function is not working however and I dont know why.Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My test game</title>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click as many as you can in 30 seconds</h1>
<input id="clickMe" type="button"  value="clickme"onclick="randomNumFunc();" />
<!-- Game Area -->
<div id="game-area">
<div id="circle1"></div>
</div>
<!-- Javascript/Jquery -->
<script src="js/JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #CEF6F5;
}

#game-area {
border: 5px solid black;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
}

#circle1 {
-moz-border-radius: 50px/50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px;
border-radius: 50px/50px;
border: solid 21px #f00;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;  
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

and Javascript/Jquery:

```
/* RNG variable */
var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

/* Picture Assignments */
var pic1 = 1;
var pic2 = 2;
var pic3 = 3;

/* RNG Code */

function randomNumFunc() {
document.getElementById('#circle1').innerHTML;
if (randomNum == 1) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$(document).onclick(function() {
  $(document).fadeTo('fast', 0);
});
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @SLaks Sorry im in a rush So i forgot to ask the most important part. Updated

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What do you see in the console?

Comment: `document.getElementById('#circle1').innerHTML;` Just use `circle1`, `#` is when you want to use selector to select the id. And even its valid, you didn't assign it to any variable, or assign value to it, what do you want the value to do?

Comment: @SLaks Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null. Im new to javascript/Jquery so What does that mean?

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to put domready into a `onclick` handler.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Thanks that stopped the console error but the function still is not fading to 1 when I press my button.

Comment: function won't fade, dom elements will, state your question more clear, what do you want the function to do, currently it's hard to guess what you expect from that function.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Sorry the the long delay. What I want to happen is that there will be a 30 second timer and in the timer the "player" has to click as many pictures in that time and for each one they click as score goes up by 1. The pictures have to randomly appear.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<input>` element should be,

`<input id="clickMe" type="button"  value="clickme"/>`

And the javaScript/jQuery code look like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
      if(randomNum == 1){
        $('#circle1').fadeTo('fast', 1);
      }
    else{
       $('#circle1').fadeTo('fast', 0);
     }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you want:

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pic1 = 1;
    var pic2 = 2;
    var pic3 = 3;

    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1); //every time you click it, will be generate a new randonNum
    console.log(randoNum); //It will show in console the number

    $('#clickMe').click(function() {

        if (randomNum  == 1) {
            $('#circle1').fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            $('#circle1').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });

});
```

and you can remove the onClick method in the input:

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button"  value="clickme" />
```